# Regular Expression to match version number pattern

Tags: php, regex

I want to match everything that looks like a version number on a string, so I started with this code

```
$str = 'ver=4.7.3/asdasd, ver=1, ver=2.5?, ver=4.7, ver=a124bcd12345';

preg_match_all("/ver=(\d+(\.\d{1,2}))/", $str, $output);

// $output
[
    "ver=4.7",
    "ver=2.5",
    "ver=4.7",
],
[
    "4.7",
    "2.5",
    "4.7",
],
[
    ".7",
    ".5",
    ".7",
],
```

With the result I got with `$output[1]` seems almost there but there is still missing, it should match these conditions:

```
1. should be a number - ok
2. n.n (4.7) - ok
3. n.n.n (4.7.1) - not being matched (it stops at 4.7)
4. 0.n - ok
```

But right now, instead of 4.7.3 it only returns 4.7.

I'm still a newbie with regular expressions so these things are still so horrible to me. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perhaps use the following *regex* :

```
(?<=ver=)[\d.]+
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z0hgLu/2)**

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/Mc851i) )

```
$str = 'ver=4.7.3/asdasd, ver=1, ver=2.5?, ver=4.7, ver=a124bcd12345';
preg_match_all('/(?<=ver=)[\d.]+/', $str, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, since I also really needed to check for the string `ver=`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work.

Regex: `ver=(\d+(\.\d){1,2})`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ckZyLy/1)